# How to Select All with a Group By as well

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, group-by

I am trying to simply run a query where I return every field from a table (Select*), however I want to condense the number of records returned by grouping on certain criteria.  So far If I do a group by after an aggregate function I can only reduce the records to the extent I want by only grouping by the aggregated function and a single other field.  If i introduce more than one field then the records expand as the group by is now going beyond just the one field.

```
SELECT SUM (Cars) as CarSales, SaleDates
FROM (SELECT Cars,
             Date,
             Color,
             Make,
             Model,
             Jetpack,
             CASE
                WHEN NVL (TO_CHAR (Date), 'NULL') LIKE 'NULL'
                THEN
                   TRUNC (TO_DATE (SYSDATE), 'dd')
                ELSE
                   Date
             END
                SalesDates
        FROM Car.DB)
WHERE TableDate= 20140501
GROUP BY SalesDates
ORDER BY SalesDates DESC
```

So in the above , I want to return only the records provided, but in addition I want to return the rest of the table data while not expanding the number of records.  I want the group by to stick to grouping by SalesDates only.

Comment: please show a sample input table and expected output results.

Comment: @user3462509: What are the table values and what is the ouput you want?